# A different step with slider value than is set, mui

Tags: reactjs

I created slider with React Material UI and I have problem, because I set step 50 but when I move point step is 200 and Why isn't 50? This is link to my example https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-scale-forked-fvm39h?file=/demo.js:415-580

```
   <Slider
    style={{ maxWidth: 500 }}
    value={value}
    min={0}
    step={50}
    max={100000}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
```

Comment: With a max of 100000, and a step of 50, you will have 2000 possible values. The width of the element is 500, so each 1 pixel your mouse moves has to be 4 steps (2000/500=4) and 4 steps is 200 (4*50). If you use the arrow keys it correctly moves by a single step (50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for including the link to the code sandbox. It looks like your issue is being caused because the range min to max distance is so much larger than the step size. If you change the max to `10000` instead of `100000`, you will see that the step does in fact increment by 50. My guess is that there is some ratio in place so that if the `stepSize / minToMaxDistance` get too small, the step size is forced to be a larger value. Realistically, this is necessary because at some point a mouse will not be accurate enough to select very small step values accurately. As DBS noted in the comment above, you can use arrow keys to move in steps of 50.

My suggestion is to either reduce the size of your `max` prop or pair this element with a text input of some kind to allow for more fine grained control.